# READ_UNCOMMITTED vs No transactions?

Tags: database, jdbc, isolation-level

What's the difference between executing SQL outside of a transaction versus executing it under READ_UNCOMMITTED isolation mode?

**Clarification**: I'm trying to understand the difference between [java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_NONE](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#TRANSACTION_NONE) and [java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED)

Comment: can you clarify what do you mean by SQL outside of a transaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TRANSACTION_NONE` means that the connection does not support transactions at all, and any attempt to impose transaction semantics on that connection should fail. I can't see this ever being useful, except perhaps in cases where you're using a "fake" database, like CSV files.

`READ_UNCOMMITTED`, on the other hand, means that the connection is using transactions, and will be able to read data from other connections' uncommitted transactions. As @Pax said, this should be used with extreme caution.

Note also the [`setTransactionIsolation`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setTransactionIsolation%28int%29) method:

> Note that `Connection.TRANSACTION_NONE` cannot be used because it specifies that transactions are not supported.

So you cannot force a connection to use `TRANSACTION_NONE` - the connection either supports transactions or it doesn't, and if it doesn't you can't mess with this method.

`READ_UNCOMMITTED` still means you're in a transaction. You still get atomic writes, and other transactions are still isolated from your writes. However, your transaction is not isolated from other peoples'. `TRANSACTION_NONE` is a free for all - no one gets isolation from anything.

Comment: What you say is true but it doesn't answer the question. What is READ_UNCOMMITTED isolating me from that TRANSACTION_NONE does not?

Comment: @Gili: I think I did. `READ_UNCOMMITTED` still means you're in a transaction. You still get atomic writes, and other transactions are still isolated from your writes. However, your transaction is not isolated from other peoples'. `TRANSACTION_NONE` is a free for all - noone gets isloation from anything.

Comment: excellent answer! If you add what you just wrote to the answer above I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

READ_UNCOMMITTED (or dirty reads) will give you information about transactions that have yet to be completed.

It's not usually a good idea since the information retrieved may be inconsistent. We've used it to avoid deadlock in reporting applications where slightly-off data doesn't matter but, if you care at all about accuracy (like charging people money, or banking), I wouldn't do it.

Executing SQL outside of a transaction (I'm assuming updates here) should not really be possible. The ACID requirements generally need transactions even for the simplest update - you may not explicitly BEGIN or COMMIT the transaction but I'll guarantee it'll be happening under the covers (at least for a decent relational DBMS).

Comment: So what does http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#TRANSACTION_NONE map to?